# Who is this person at the edge of Fangorn?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-two-towers

In **Lord of the Rings The Two Towers** Aragorn, Gimli and Legolas rests at night beside the forest of Fangorn. There they sees an old man in white. Afterwards their horses also left them. Gimli then suspects that it is Saruman.

So who was he? I don't remember clearly but I think that Gandalf denied that it was him. Is it made clear anywhere who he is?